# How to grab live text from a URL?

Tags: php, python, bash, wget, keep-alive

Im trying to grab all data(text) coming from a URL which is constantly sending text, I tried using PHP but that would mean having the script running the whole time which it isn’t really made for (I think). So I ended up using a BASH script.

At the moment I use wget (I couldn’t get CURL to output the text to a file)

```
wget --tries=0 --retry-connrefused http://URL/ --output-document=./output.txt
```

So wget seems to be working pretty well, apart from one thing, every time I re-start the script wget will clear the output.txt file and start filling it again, which isn’t what I want. **Is there a way to tell wget to append to the txt file?**

Also, is this the best way to capture the live stream of data?
Should I use a different language like Python or …?

Comment: Have you tried `--continue` option of wget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `wget --tries=0 --retry-connrefused $URL -O - >> output.txt`.

Explanation: the parameters `-O` is short for `--output-document`, and a dash `-` means *standard output*.

The line `command > file` means write "write output of `command` to `file`", and `command >> file` means "*append* output of `command` to `file`" which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Curl doesn't follow redirects by default and outputs nothing if there is a redirect. I always specify the `--location` option just in case. If you want to use `curl`, try:

```
curl http://example.com --location --silent >> output.txt
```

The `--silent` option turns off the progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

while true 
do 
wget -q -O - http://example.com >> filename # -O - outputs to the screen 
sleep 2 # sleep 2 sec 
done

Answer (score 0):

curl http://URL/ >> output.txt

the >> redirects the output from curl to output.txt, appending to any data already there.  (If it was just > output.txt - that would overwrite the contents of output.txt each time you ran it).

Comment: This is one of the things I first tired but it doesn’t work as it just  shows to the screen the download progress and outputs nothing to the text file.